# Creating a image browser in PyQt?? Where to start?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I would like to make something like this using pyqt:
https://vimeo.com/110260781

It is a image sequence player/browser. I have basic pyqt knowledge, not enough to know how to start a project like this. Or even what qt classes to look at.

So I guess the hardest is the viewer. How would I go about making a image sequence viewer. What media packages are available within Qt that deals with media playback.

Any help would be awesome!

Here is a quick mockup 
http://i67.tinypic.com/5347k3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do media playback with the widgets in the [`phonon`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/phonon.html) subpackage.

Depending on how complex you want to get with the layout, you have a few choices.  If you just want to show a single video at a time, just use the normal `QLayout` classes.

If you want to do more complex stuff like in the example you linked, with tiled video players, possibly with the ability to scale each video player and select them, etc., then you probably want to use a `QGraphicsView`/`QGraphicsScene`.  It will basically allow you to draw the widget any way you want, and it allows you to embed other widgets (like the `phonon` media widgets) using the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` class.

Comment: Thx, there isn't much info documenting the phonon package. LoL anyway, thanks for the direction. I'll investigate those.

Comment: You may also want to consider purchasing a license for [RV](http://www.tweaksoftware.com/products/rv).  It's a video player that is completely scriptable with python and integrates with Qt/PyQt.